# NestJS REST controller not picking up @Body from PATCH request (VSCode REST Client)

Tags: api, rest, vscode-extensions, rest-client, rfc2616

I have this test request using the VS Code REST Client extension:

```
PATCH http://localhost:3000/auth/3

content-type: application/json

{ "email": "new.email3@gmail.com" }
```

On the receiving end, the NestJS app listening on this endpoint *isn't* picking up the body of the PATCH request, so there's no update within the NestJS service responsible for update requests.

Here's the controller method/endpoint in NestJS:

```
  @Patch('/:id')
  updateUser(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() body: UpdateUserDto) {
    
    console.log('body: ', body);

    return this.usersService.update(parseInt(id), body);
  }
```

And the result of the debugging console log above:

```
body:  {}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra line between the URI request and the request headers was the problem. One must put the request headers directly after the URI as such:

```
PATCH http://localhost:3000/auth/3
content-type: application/json

{ "email": "new.email3@gmail.com" }
```

Reading the section on [request headers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client) on the VS Code REST Client Extension page, the author clearly states:
`The lines immediately after the request line to first empty line are parsed as Request Headers`

Then the body comes through as expected:

```
body:  { email: 'new.email3@gmail.com' }
```

Hope this saves someone else the time it took me to figure it out.

Comment: Does it really work with multipart/form-data